# Clean up open and closed brackets in RDD using Scala

Tags: regex, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

after doing few transformations on a file using spark and scala i got an result like the below

```
(451,M,(BC-B,(21104246,321.50)))
(454,M,(OC,(21104751,361.00)))
(147,M,(OC,(20404588,340.00)))
(155,M,(BC-B,(20405733,347.00)))
```

but I need to remove the brackets and expecting the output as the below because I need to convert the rdd to dataframe

```
454,M,OC,21104751,361.00  
451,M,BC-B,21104246,321.50
147,M,OC,20404588,340.00
155,M,BC-B,20405733,347.00
```

any help is appreciable!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just pattern match it out:

```
rdd.map{case (a,b,(c,(d,e))) => (a,b,c,d,e)}.toDF()
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply,I have used replace all function and it is working fine....i will try yours also and check